# Como passar o this.state de uma tela para outra tela com React Native

Tags: react, react-native

Galera, sou novo no `React Native`, o que eu quero fazer é pegar um `this.state` da tela 1 por exemplo e utilizá-lo na tela 2 para printar esse mesmo `this.state`. Fiz um exemplo bem grotesco para tentar explicar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Inputs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            num1: 0,
            num2: 0,
            resultadoSoma: 0,
        };

        this.calcularSoma = this.calcularSoma.bind(this);
    }

    calcularSoma() {
        let calculoSoma = 0;

        calculoSoma = parseFloat(this.state.num1) + parseFloat(this.state.num2);

        let s = this.state;
        s.resultadoSoma = calculoSoma;
        this.setState(s);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                 onChangeText={num1 => {
                     this.setState({ num1 });
                 }}/>
                <TextInput
                 onChangeText={num2 => {
                     this.setState({ num2 });
                 }}/>
                <TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.3} onPress={this.calcularSoma}>
                    <Text style={styles.textoBotaoContinuar}>CALCULAR</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <Text>RESULTADO: {this.state.resultadoSoma}</Text>
           </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Como pego esse
`<Text>RESULTADO: {this.state.resultadoSoma}</Text>`
e mostro ta tela 2?

Qualquer ajuda será de grande valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para passar dados de uma tela para outra você poderá utilizar o componente [react-native-navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation#react-navigation) conseguindo de maneira bem simples passar os valores para a tela que deseja.

**Exemplo de uso para este caso**

Utilizando dois componentes (telas). Gostaríamos de passar o estado **resutadoSoma** da `tela1` para a `tela2`

Componente que passa o valor(tela1):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('tela2', {resultado: this.state.resutadoSoma})
```

Componente que recebe o valor(tela2):

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.resultado
```

Comment: Consegui passar os valores de uma tela para outra usando esse recurso do react-native-navigation. Muito obrigado :D